# windows 11 think's it's in preinstallation after rebuilding the bcd store

Tags: windows, bcdboot

One day i tried to start my pc and got the blue screen with the  code: 0xc00000e and following an tutorial i formated the 100mb boot partition and rebuild it with the command

```shell
bcdboot c:\windows /l en-us /s z: /f UEFI
```

My windows booted fine after that but thinks whare not right.
The first thing i've notice was that my sleep and hibernate whare missing from the power dropdown in the start menu and when i tried to check the power options in control panel i saw this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83ffH.png)

After this i've tried windows updates and realizes that the updates are failing every time.

Now i'm thinking there's something wrong with the recovery partition and i've run

```shell
reagentc /info
```

output: REAGENTC.EXE: A target Windows installation must be specified.

Wird
Next i've tried enabling reagentc

```shell
reagentc /enable
```

output:

```
Enables the local copy of the Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE).

This command can be used from the running operating system without additional
parameters, or from the Windows Preinstallation Environment (Windows PE) using
the optional /osguid parameter.
```

How can i be in Windows Preinstallation Environment?
confused i've runned bcdedit

output:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows PreInstallation Environment
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
nx                      OptOut
winpe                   Yes
```

as you can see it reports that my windows installation is in Preinstallation Environment which explains all the problems i'm having.

I've tried rebuilding the BCD store servil times without any change.
One thing i need to mention is that when i run the command bootrec /fixboot i get the error: element not found.

I'm tiring to fix this for a mount now and i'm stuck.
Any help whit be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your screenshot isn’t of a WinPE. All I see is the description of your EFI entry isn’t accurate. Recovery partition isn’t required and isn’t special. I can be recreated by booting to an ISO.

Comment: yes, i even tries bcdboot c:\windows /l en-us /s z: /f ALL but i know for a  fact that my  os and bios is uefi

Comment: YES both my os and bios are UEFI

Comment: @Ramhound if you take a lock at the output from bcdedit you can see  the last line says winpe                   Yes

Comment: @John it's not a virtual machine and i'm not dual booting it is my only os

Comment: @john i've tried doing an repair install the problem is that windows setup is not seeing the existing windows installation probably because it is in PE mode. The funny thing is that id i run setup.exe from windows it behaves like i'm booting from the installation media and nor like an inplace upgrade

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_11-windows_install/windows-11-thinks-its-in-preinstallation-after/20cc48b1-6493-490c-a2d3-e84e66e2ff4e